# Why isn't theming metioned for combined flair?

Tags: discussion, bug, flair

I have been using my SO flair for a while now and have now achieved sufficient reputation to use the combined flair for all SE sites (even though I only use SO). I put the new combined flair on my website, and then decided to add `?theme=clean` to the end, and it worked.

However, when I went to the flair page in SO, there was no mention that the combined flair supported theming, but I obviously does. Why was theming it not mentioned on that page?

[image: Screenshot of my flair page]

Notice that the instructions for theming are only under the SO flair.

Comment: Where is this flair page you are talking about? In `users/id/display_name/flair` (accessible from your profile > flair), it has this: `(to change the theme, add ?theme=clean or ?theme=dark or ?theme=hotdog to the end of the image URL)`

Comment: Yes that is the page. From the writer's train of thought, it seems that the theming he is referring to is for the SO flair only.

Comment: OK, I see your point now. There is no example for the combined flair, and the description is below the per-site flair. Would you mind making a screenshot? It would help getting more people to become aware of the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason that the same exact text needs to be mentioned again for the combined flair? Perhaps they could just move it to a different spot so it's more clear that it applies to both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can see that both html flair tags (combine and for SO) are same. Except the `href` details. Which is just to direct user to related site.

As a developer I would prefer to go for reuse code and class and object and what ever which makes easy to change.

So I guess they do follow the same. So the `?theme=clean` tag must be there for StackExchange flair too.

How ever I haven't try but from the basis of similarity between flair. I'm pretty sure that it works for both.